# Makfile ERROR: make: ../objects/%.o:: No such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, raspberry-pi4, makefile

I've been trying to compile my OS (Not a linux OS, my very own) for Raspberry Pi 4 correctly for about a week total now I keep having to ask questions but whenever one gets answered I have another error.

Anyways when I try to use the make command I get this error:

```
../objects/%.o: ../src/kernel/%.s gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf/bin/aarch64-none-elf-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -c ../src/kernel -o objects
make: ../objects/%.o:: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:111: clean] Error 127
```

Here's the makefile there's a lot of unused code that I kept in just in case:

```makefile
CFLAGS= -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -mcpu=cortex-a72+nosimd
CXXFLAGS= -ggdb3 -O0 -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -mcpu=cortex-a72+nosimd
CSRCFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS= -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib
IMG_PATH= ../
BUILD_BACK_TWO= ../../../build
CFILES= $(wildcard *.c)
OFILES= $(CFILES:.c=.o)
GCCPATH= gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf
GCCFLAGS= -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles
GCCPATHAARCH= $(GCCPATH)/aarch64-none-elf/bin
GCCPATHBIN= $(GCCPATH)/bin
ASMCFLAGS= -f elf32 -F dwarf -g -w+all
ASM= -s

# Location of the files
THIS_DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
KER_SRC = ../src/kernel
KER_MENU_SRC = ../src/kernel/menu
KER_HEAD = ../include
COMMON_SRC = ../src/common
UI_IMAGES = ../images/ui
SPE_GAMES = ../spe_games
DINOBYTE = $(SPE_GAMES)/dinobyte
OBJ_DIR = objects
ASMSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.s)
KERSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.c)
#KERSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.c)
COMMONSOURCES = $(wildcard $(COMMON_SRC)/*.c)
KERSOURCESCPP = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.cpp)
DINOBYTESOURCES = $(wildcard $(DINOBYTE)/src/*.cpp)
#KERSOURCESCPP = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.cpp)
#KERMENUSOURCESC = $(wildcard $(KER_MENU_SRC)/*.c)
#KERMENUSOURCESCPP = $(wildcard $(KER_MENU_SRC)/*.cpp)
UISOURCES = $(wildcard $(UI_IMAGES)/*.png)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.s, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(ASMSOURCES))
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.s, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(ASMSOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERSOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERSOURCESCPP))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(COMMON_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(COMMONSOURCES))
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_MENU_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERMENUSOURCESC))
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_MENU_SRC)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERMENUSOURCESCPP))
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(UI_IMAGES)/%.png, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(UISOURCES))

#Dinobyte objects [include Dinobyte headers here] (do later)
#OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(DINOBYTESOURCES)/src/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(DINOBYTESOURCES))

#Headers
HEADERS = $(wildcard $(KER_HEAD)/*.h)


IMG_NAME=SuperPiOS

#build: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
#$(CC) -T linker.ld -o $(IMG_NAME).elf $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) #needs indent
#$(OBJCOPY) $(IMG_NAME).elf -O binary $(IMG_NAME).img #needs indent

#$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.s
#mkdir -p $(@D) #needs indent
#$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -c $< -o $@ #needs indent

BUILDKERS = $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.s \
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $(KER_SRC) -o $(OBJ_DIR)

BUILDKERC = $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.c \
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

BUILDKERCARCH = $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/%.c \
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

BUILDSRCCPP = $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.cpp \
    $(GCCPATHBIN) arm-none-eabi-cpp $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

BUILDSRCCPPARCH = $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/%.cpp \
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

BUILDCOMMONC = $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(COMMON_SRC)/%.c \
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc $(GCCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_MENU_SRC)/%.c
#   mkdir -p $(@D)
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -I$(KER_HEAD) -c $< -o $@ $(CSRCFLAGS)

#$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_MENU_SRC)/%.cpp
#   mkdir -p $(@D)
#   $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -I$(KER_HEAD) -c $< -o $@ $(CSRCFLAGS)

BUILD = $(IMG_NAME)%.img: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
BUILD += $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles $(OBJECTS) -T linker.ld -o $(IMG_NAME).elf
BUILD += $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-objcopy -O binary $(IMG_NAME).elf  $(IMG_NAME).img

clean:
    $(BUILDKERS)
    $(BUILDKERC)
    $(BUILDKERCARCH)
    $(BUILDSRCCPP)
    $(BUILDSRCCPPARCH)
    $(BUILDCOMMONC)
    $(BUILD)
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    rm $(IMG_NAME).elf
    rm $(IMG_NAME).img

run: build
    qemu-system-arm -m 128 -no-reboot -M raspi4 -serial stdio -kernel kernel.elf

#dbg:
#$(GDB) kernel.elf

#dbgrun: build gdbinit
#qemu-system-arm -m 128 -no-reboot -M raspi4 -serial stdio -kernel kernel.elf -S -s

#.PHONY: gdbinit

#gdbinit:
#echo "target remote localhost:1234" > .gdbinit
#echo "break kernel_main" >> .gdbinit
```

Anyways thanks in Advance

Comment: I mean... this isn't even _close_ to a valid makefile.  You can't put entire pattern rules into variables, then put those variables inside recipes.  And you surely don't want to put all the _build_ commands inside a _clean_ rule, which is probably supposed to clean up your workspace by deleting all the generated files like object files.  I think you need to read the first one or two chapters of the GNU make manual to get some basic info on make: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html  Try writing a very simple makefile that just compiles one file.

Comment: @MadScientist Well I've been trying a lot to get this to work but no matter what I do it seems I can't get it to work.

Comment: That's why I suggested (a) reading the intro sections in the manual and (b) starting with a very simple makefile that just builds one thing.  If you can get that to work then you'll be well on your way to understanding makefile syntax and can add to that.  Also, you still have the issue I told you about in the previous question you asked: your `clean` rule is still the first explicit rule in your makefile.  The previous question contained a makefile that was MUCH closer to being usable than this one.